# TeamViewer always on 800x600 resolution

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, teamviewer

I want to work on a Remote Machine that does not have a display attached. I am using TeamViewer for this purpose. When I connect to the target its Screen resolution is set to 800x600 (Windows 7).

The Display Settings tell me that the device is "Mobile PC Display". The resolution dropdown just offers 800x600.

Any idea how to change the resolution/display?

Comment: No. Your question doesn't belong here

Comment: IS this machine running in safe mode and have you verfied that it is not normally 800x600?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting display resolution beyond 1024x768 with headless Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/990398/setting-display-resolution-beyond-1024x768-with-headless-windows-10)