# Forcing a resolution on a computer without monitor

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, resolution, vnc

I have this computer running an embedded version of Windows 7 and it does not have any monitor attached. It is only accessed with VNC (alternatice for RDP) so a monitor is not needed. The problem is that I really need it to display 1680*1050 and that is possible when I hook up a monitor, but when I take away the monitor it only has a few resolutions left on which it can run. None of them is 1650*1080.

So is there a way to "force" the right resolution? I know there are other questions like this, but they did not have the right answer for me. Switching to RDP is not an option BTW.

I am also quite curious as to why it can only display the right resolution on a monitor. If it is at all possible to give me some insight into this I would appreciate that.

Comment: I had (well have) a similar problem and I have no found a decent solution yet. Best workarounds I have atm are: 1) Use VGA and short circuit the 'monitor detected' pin, then list all modi and set one. (Ugly, but also often usedto get dedicated CUDA cards to work without attaching a monitor). Or you can attach a monitor (no need to actually look at it). Atm I use the last, but it is large, bulky and not suited to embedded solutions. It will be interesting to see what answer people come up with.

Comment: Hm I would not necessarily be against the first option.... If you are sure that this works, you should add it as answer....

Comment: @Hennes I cannot find any information on the method you suggested. Can you maybe give me a link or something? Maybe I am googling for the wrong things.

Comment: http://www.overclock.net/t/384733/the-30-second-dummy-plug

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So this is how I solved my problem:
There is this thing called a "Dummy plug". Basically it is just a VGA cable with one of the RGB signal lines connected to GND through a 50-150 Ohm resistor. The computer will then beleive that a monitor is attached, but it can't detect the resolutions it can display so it displays all resolutions.

Comment: As a side note: https://www.headlessghost.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to uncheck 'hide resolution that monitor can't display and you may get 1440 times 900 (close to native), 1650 times 1050 (native) and even 1776 times 1000 (above native but maybe a little 'thin' pixels because your aspect ratio is 16:10 and it may look 6 to 7 percent compressed on the sides.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as the name of the checkbox suggests: that only works when a monitor is attached.

Comment: With a second monitor or when you're in the options panel?

Comment: In any case it only works when a monitor is attached. Setting the resolution and the removing the monitor does work, but only till the PC reboots

Answer (score 0):

If you have physical access to the PC, you can use a display port emulator such as this one
[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B071CGCTMY](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071CGCTMY)
It "tricks" your PC into thinking there is an actual DP monitor attached and provides a wide variety of resolution options.  For $7, seems like its well worth it rather than cobbling together from adapters and resistors.
This is for display port, so you might need something else for DVI or HDMI.
I tried the Regedit hacks but couldn't get them to work (Win 7 32-bit with PCIe graphics card).