# Change screen resolution to higher resolution with no monitor attached

Tags: display, resolution, windows-server-2008-r2, logmein

### Backstory:

I have a situation where I have a set of servers that never have anyone physically at the console (in the server room).  They have a KVM attached to them (some do) but the KVM never connects to the server.  So as far as the servers are concerned (I think) they believe they have no monitors attached.

I use things like LogMeIn to connect to the server.  LogMeIn uses the console screen to display the current session of the server as it were "at the console aka standing in front of the server".  Unlike using RDP where a new session is created with the resolution matching the screen resolution of the PC you are using to connect to the remote host.

### Issue:

I try to connect to the server using LogMeIn.  When I connected before I noticed the max resolution was 1280x1024.  Now it's max is 1024x768.  Nothing I do seems to make that max resolution increase.

[image]

### Goal:

Simple enough, I want to find some way to increase the system's max screen resolution.  I don't care if the local physical monitor will never show an image due to errors like "out of range" etc.  I will never use a monitor on these servers.  Everything will always be done remotely.  Also I DO NOT want to use any extra hardware to accomplish this goal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forcing a resolution on a computer without monitor](http://superuser.com/questions/1035491/forcing-a-resolution-on-a-computer-without-monitor)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 it's very similar but I wanted to reference LogMeIn specifically.  I was hoping there was a work around.  Also, that question is asked and answered.  That user was happy with adding new hardware to their environment.  That is not an option for me.

Comment: Though RDP usually opens a new session it can connect to the console session, truly as if you were at the server.

Answer (score 0):

LogMeIn changes the resolution base on the best optimization for the remote session. To change the resolution, follow these steps

1. On the main remote control screen, tap the Gear (Settings) icon.
2. Click Resolution.
3. Click prefeered screen resolution
4. Click Settings
5. Save Settings

[Source](https://secure.logmein.com/welcome/webhelp/EN/Pro/LogMeIn/t_Ignition_iP_Display_Resolution.html)

Comment: This answer in no way allows me to INCREASE the system's max screen resolution.  It only allows you to choose a LOWER resolution than what the MAX resolution currently is set at.