# How to keep the windows 10 pc works as the monitor is connected while it's not. (power setting issue)

Tags: windows, windows-10

It sounds like a strange question. I am using a windows 10 pc as a server with Chrome Remote. I noticed when the windows pc not connected to the monitor, some apps can't work normally. Also when I unplug the HDMI from the windows pc, the Chrome Remote disconnected (although It can be reconnected). It seems like a power setting issue. (something disabled while not connecting to a monitor). I switched the power option to high performance but still can't fix the issue. Does anyone know how to fix it? It must have a power setting for servers without a monitor connected. Thanks a lot.

Comment: When the monitor is off Windows switches to a "simulated default monitor" that has a resolution of 1024x768. Such a resolution change can have the effects you describe: See also https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/resolution-of-4k-displays-changes-to-1024-x-768/71275d81-5d39-4abc-b007-68642e5849b0 and https://superuser.com/q/990398/62676

Comment: thanks for providing this valuable clue!