# Monitor enters sleep mode much earlier than set in any settings or power settings. On resume resolution is extremely low and windows are repositioned

Tags: windows-10, display, resolution, sleep

Two-folded problem, first: My monitor enters sleepmode much much earlier than any settings. Like in between 1-5 minutes time.
Both power options in the traditional control panel, the new one in Win10 and screensaver(99min) settings are all set to 3 hours.
The GPU (AMD) settings are default and not have any power-saving stuff going on.
On the monitor itself I have disabled energy saving and automatic standby options.

So as far as I can see, there is no way the monitor is going to sleep when I'm away for a couple of minutes, yet it happen every time.

Now enter problem 2: Upon waking the monitor (device connected/discovered sound plays) the resolution is super low (original is 3440x1440 and it becomes something like 720p). Only way to fix it is to turn off the monitor with the power button and on again. It plays the device connected sound and all is well, except all open windows are now squished into a smaller size so I have to re-arrange all my work every time.

What could be causing this? How do I fix it?

Note: I have tried to reset power options to defaults, then set it back to something like 3 hours until sleep. No change.

In regedit under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers\Configuration\` I have a bunch of records. I tried manually changing the low-res values to the original ultra wide, but it's not really working.

[registry pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zasji.jpg)

Comment: What registry values have you changed? Make sure to edit the values mentioned in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1334787/62676).

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the tip. I've tried this and it doesn't change anything. I changed all of my 'NOEDID' items which were 2, but as you can see I have a lot more. Is there any way for me to know which one of the items in \Configuration\ is the one being used? Can I delete them?